# Unable to get the text of an element usng selenium web driver in Jasmine test cases

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, tdd, selenium-chromedriver

I need to get the text value of an element using selenium web driver as follows.

```
this.driver.findElement(selenium.By.id('floor-name')).then(function(element){
        expect(element.getText()).toMatch("Floor 1");       
})
```

I am using following versions of libs

```
node v6.2.1
selenium-webdriver 2.53.2
jasmine v2.4.1
jasmine-core v2.4.
```

1

This is the error I am getting while running the test

```
Message:
    Expected ManagedPromise::370 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"} to match 'Floor 1'.
  Stack:
    Error: Expected ManagedPromise::370 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"} to match 'Floor 1'.
        at /home/tharsan/tmp/selenium/spec/cleanViewSpec.js:46:27
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/home/tharsan/tmp/selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/home/tharsan/tmp/selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/home/tharsan/tmp/selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you passing the element here? you have to resolve the getText promise. Try this:

```
 this.driver.findElement(selenium.By.id('floor-name')).getText().then(function(text){
    expect(text).toMatch("Floor 1");       
});
```

Comment: Yes. it answers the question. But could you please suggest a way to debug these test specs using  Selenium web driver + Jasmine :)

Comment: glad it helped! Please accept the answer if it solved your issue.
for debugging, if you are using protractor you can refer this link :https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md

Comment: You may refer this https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/8f988e07cc316a48e0ff94d8ff823c95142532e9/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js#L1884  to get each of the web driver method definitions.  It returns a promise that will get resolved to the element text.